# Facebook Debugger tool blank page

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-debugger

I was trying to debug a page of blog, but the debugger tool wont allow me to. Any idea why is this happening?

**Debugger Tool with the page link:**
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturalthrone.com%2Fblog%2Fartigo%2F9-must-dos-to-overcome-constipation-bloating-and-bowel-disease

**Blog page link**: https://www.naturalthrone.com/blog/artigo/9-must-dos-to-overcome-constipation-bloating-and-bowel-disease

This White Page happens with all the website's blog posts.

Comment: File a bug report, and ask them to fix it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: already did :/ thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and I solved it by changing the number in the post slug to a word.
For example:

```
https://www.naturalthrone.com/blog/artigo/nine-must-dos-to-overcome-constipation-bloating-and-bowel-disease
                                          ^^^^
```

It appears the Facebook Debugger bugs out if there's a number as the first character of the post slug.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I reported the bug to facebook just like Cbroe suggested, and they fixed it last night! :D  Now, do I delete this question or is there a place where I can mark as 'solved' ?